# Execute function when input variable is changed in other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I nmy subcomponent, I have an input called "data"

```
@Input() data: Array<any> = [];
```

I take a copy of this variable when my component is initiated

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.data)
}
```

In my main component it can happen that I need to add something to this data variable.

**Main Comp:**

```
// this.nextStatusesToSelect = data for subcomponent
let dataIndex = this.nextStatusesToSelect.findIndex(i => i.ID === e.ID);
if (dataIndex === -1) {
    this.nextStatusesToSelect.push(e);        
}
```

I can see that in my subcomponent my `data`
 variable gets correctly updated, however this means I also need to update the copy.

> How can I trigger a function in my subcomponent when my `data`
>   variable changes?

I've been reading about using`OnChanges` however this doesn't seem to work for me at all since it doesn't get triggerd.

```
   ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log(changes);
    }
```

Comment: When you change data input, you should create new object. Try after changing data array do: data = data.slice(); and ngOnChanges will fire;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

`this.nextStatusesToSelect.push(e)`

try this

`this.nextStatusesToSelect = [...this.nextStatusesToSelect, e]`

This should trigger a change in your `ngOnChanges()` method.

[This article](https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487) also might be helpful in finding the best way of what are you trying to achieve and shows advantages of Immutable approach in Angular.